# How do I generate a token in PHP to post the my Express-based app?

Tags: php, node.js, csrf

I have a node app with the express-csrf module. I also have another site built in PHP on a different domain. I would like to create a form on my PHP site which submits to the Node-based site. With the csrf protection I obviously can't do that.

How do I generate a token in PHP to post the my Express-based app?

Comment: Find out how your Node module generates CSRF tokens, and replicate that in PHP. This might use a hash of all the form names, plus a secret string, concatenated. I'm not familiar with Node, but wonder if the source for "express-csrf" is available, and so the generation method can be traced?

Comment: Ah, [have a look at this](https://github.com/hanssonlarsson/express-csrf/blob/master/lib/index.js) (I am guessing that is what you are referring to). That stores something in the session based on the last access time, so replicating that on a server where that session is unavailable is tricky. Can you turn off CSRF protection on this form, and implement your own using a shared secret?